# android restore in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

my android app has an in app purchase option, where you can unlock the full version.

this works fine.
but now a customer told me, that he unlock the full version for a few days.
now he change his device (same google account) and he would like to restore his in app purchase.

in my test phase i could press on my "buy button" and the google server tells me if i do this purchase before or not.

but the customer told me, that he purchase this in app option now for a second time and this is not right (i canceled the last order)

where is my mistake?

**FullVersion Activity**

```
public class FullVersion extends AppCompatActivity implements IabBroadcastListener {

    Intent intent = null;
    boolean mIsPremium = false;
    static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "IAP-NAME";
    static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;

    IabHelper mHelper;
    IabBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

    Button BuyFullVersion;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullversion);

        BuyFullVersion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BuyFullVersion);


        BuyFullVersion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String payload = "";
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(FullVersion.this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
            }
        });





        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "XXXXXXXXX";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // GOOGLE ACCOUNT MISSING
                    return;
                }

                if (mHelper == null) return;
                mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(FullVersion.this);
                IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });



    }







    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (mHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e("-->","Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e("-->", "ERROR");
            }
            else {
                if (inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM) == true) {
                    // SET SHARED PREFERENCES BOOLEAN "FULLVERSION" = TRUE
                }
            }


        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
       }
   };


    @Override
    public void receivedBroadcast() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        return true;
    }



    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

            if (mHelper == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e("-->","Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }


            if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }




            if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                Log.e("-->","Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
                return;
            }
        }
    };


    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

            if (mHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // SET SHARED PREFERENCES BOOLEAN "FULLVERSION" = TRUE
            } else {
                Log.e("-->","Error while consuming: " + result);
            }
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before launch purchase flow you can check if this user already purchase or not..
and according to that you can manage it.

```
public void AlreadyPurchase()
{

    try {

        alreadyPurchasedString=mHelper.getAllPurchases().toString();
        Log.d(TAG+ "Purchases: ",""+alreadyPurchasedString);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(alreadyPurchasedString);
        if(array.length() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);    
               String productId=row.getString("productId");  //this will get the product id's that has been purchased.
               if(productId.equals("YOUR SKU"))
               {
                    mPrefs.editPrefs();
                    mPrefs.putBoolean(PrefsManager.KEY_FULL_VERSION, true);
                    mPrefs.commitPrefs();
                    Log.d(TAG +"To be restored:", " PRODUCT ID's "+productId);
               }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You have not any in app purchase earlier");
        }
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}
```

Comment: i testing my code of post 1 again. i log me in with my google account and made an "purchase" (promo code).the full version is unlocked. i switch the device, log me in with the same google account, download my app and open it. the full version isn't unlock yet. but if I open the Full Version activity, i get directly the alert "Full Version was restored" this alert is in the code part 'if (inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM) == true) {
// SET SHARED PREFERENCES BOOLEAN "FULLVERSION" = TRUE }' i think my code works correctly now. will the customer kidding me or can be there another problem?